# cannot compile unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.2.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.10.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':lintVitalRelease'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':lintClassPath'.
  >   Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.12.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >
  > - file:/C:/d/programs/android sdk/extras/m2repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.pom
  > - file:/C:/d/programs/android sdk/extras/m2repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar
  > - file:/C:/d/programs/android sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.pom
  > - file:/C:/d/programs/android sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.12/groovy-all-2.4.12.jar
  >     … and more...